# How do I root my Kyocera Echo? 

Tags: rooting

I've seen instructions for many other devices, but nothing for the Kyocera Echo. How do I root my Kyocera Echo without completely screwing up my phone? I've tried the Z4root to no avail. What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods available, but I'm posting one found on [ognimnella](http://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=3953573)'s post on XDA, found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1301729). The following are the steps he provides:

> A little Information:
>
> I will be using my directory to my SDK folder for this tutorial
>   (C:\sdk\tools) but whatever your directory is to SDK is what you will
>   use.
>
> Things you will need:
>
> Android SDK (already set up)
>
> A Kyocera Echo (duh!)
>
> zergRush (XDA root exploit)
>
> Root method:
>
> 1. Download zergRush and put the file (not the zip) in your tools folder of sdk
>
> Open your CMD promt, then redirect to SDK (just type exactly what I
>   type after you're in SDK)
>
> (cd c:\sdk\tools) <-- SDK redirect
>
> adb shell rm -r /data/local/temp/*
>
> adb push zergRush /data/local/temp/zergRush
>
> adb shell
>
> chmod 755 /data/local/temp/zergRush
>
> /data/local/zergRush
>
> then you should see this:
>
> [**] Zerg rush - Android 2.2/2.3 local root [**] (C) 2011
>   Revolutionary. All rights reserved. [**] Parts of code from
>   Gingerbreak, (C) 2010-2011 The Android Exploid Crew. [+] Found a
>   GingerBread ! 0x00017118[*] Sending 149 zerglings ...[*] Trying a new
>   path ...[*] Sending 149 zerglings ...[*] Trying a new path ...[*]
>   Sending 149 zerglings ...[*] Trying a new path ...[*] Sending 149
>   zerglings ... [+] Zerglings caused crash (good news): 0x401219c4
>   0x0054[*] Researching Metabolic Boost ... [+] Speedlings on the go !
>   0xafd260a9 0xafd39f9f[*] Poping 24 more zerglings[*] Sending 173
>   zerglings ... [+] Rush did it ! It's a GG, man !  [+] Killing ADB and
>   restarting as root..enjoy!
>
> 1. Afterwards, you will have to manually push SuperUser and Busybox (DO NOT UNPLUG THE PHONE)
>
> find the SU and Busybox files here
>
> Then, ADB push them with these commands:
>
> Type: adb push GingerBreak /data/local/tmp/GingerBreak
>
> Type: adb push Superuser.apk /data/local/tmp/Superuser.apk
>
> Type: adb push su /data/local/tmp/su
>
> Type: adb push busybox /data/local/tmp/busybox
>
> AND THERE YOU HAVE IT, YOUR PHONE IS NOW ROOTED. HAVE FUN MODDING AND
>   DOING WHATEVER ELSE. AS SOON AS SARIDNOUR AND H.T.E. COME OUT WITH THE
>   RECOVERY, WE ARE ON TO CUSTOM ROMS!!!!

Another method can be found on [Android Central](http://forums.androidcentral.com/sprint-kyocera-echo/77428-how-root-echo.html) forums, and there is a [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cG2DtNAHZR8) that goes through the process, but he may be using Z4root.